# For loop is stopping

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that returns the similarity of words, but the loop stops after processing only the first argument! For example, if I execute `example.py hello there` the program returns this:

```
hello is close to: 

held, heel, helpt, hele, Hallo, het, helaas, half, helden, heb, veel, Meld, zelf, heeft, beeld, alle, wel, Rel, Geld, cel, geld, Alle, hoezo, 
 there is close to:
```

Here is my code:

```
def create_data():
    data =defaultdict(int)
    value = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        [ident, user, text, terms] = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        for word in terms.split():
            data[word] = value

    return data

def find_closest(word):

    data = create_data()
    data_with_distance= defaultdict(int)
    for key in data:
        distance = lev_dist(word, key)
        data_with_distance[key] = distance
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(data_with_distance.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:

        for w in sys.argv[1:]:
            print("\n",w, "is close to:\n")
            closest = find_closest(w)
            closest_words = [k for k, v in closest.items() if v < 4]
            #minimal_distance = list(closest.values())[0]
            for close in closest_words:
                print(close, end=", ")

    else:
        sys.stderr.write("no argument\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What does `create_data` return?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Reproduction isn't possible with the code you provided.

Comment: A default dictionary with all words in a text as key and 0 as value.

Comment: Figure out what's producing an empty sequence: `create_data()`? `find_closest()`? the list comprehension defining `closest_words`?

Comment: `create_data()` seems very suspicious.

Comment: @chepner that is the problem. Nothing of these is producing an empty sequence.

Comment: @Samwise Why do you think that?

Comment: It takes no input, and we can't see what it does, and it's upstream from everything else.  Try calling `create_data()` once at the start of your program -- do you now get no output at all?

Comment: @Samwise If I add this to the start of the program, the program will fail. Take a look at it, I added the function to the post.

Comment: Yup, that's the problem.  It's non-idempotent because it consumes the entire `stdin` stream the first time you run it.  Call it once, cache the result, and pass it into `find_closest`.

Comment: `create_data` produces a non-empty sequence *once*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache the results of `create_data` if you want to reuse it:

```
def find_closest(word, data):  # take data as param here
    data_with_distance= defaultdict(int)
    for key in data:
        distance = lev_dist(word, key)
        data_with_distance[key] = distance
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(data_with_distance.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}


def main():
    data = create_data()  # load data from stdin ONCE

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:

        for w in sys.argv[1:]:
            print("\n",w, "is close to:\n")
            closest = find_closest(w, data)  # pass data as param here
            closest_words = [k for k, v in closest.items() if v < 4]
            #minimal_distance = list(closest.values())[0]
            for close in closest_words:
                print(close, end=", ")
```

Another option would be to stick a caching decorator on `create_data`:

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def create_data():
    data = defaultdict(int)
    value = 0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        [ident, user, text, terms] = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        for word in terms.split():
            data[word] = value
    return data
```

This "fixes" the function by making it cache the result from the first time you run it, and return the same result on subsequent calls instead of actually executing the function.

In a function that takes parameters, the caching would happen based on the parameters; since this function takes no parameters, it'll just cache a single return value.  If the function had a *desirable* side effect you would not want to cache it like this, but in this case the side effect is *undesirable* so sticking a `@cache` on it is a very easy solution.